# Loop to look for the closest value in a specific range

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have to run the code twice to get the right answer.

The bug is somewhere in the for loop commented as "finds static.press cell location"

```vb
Sub find()
Dim A As Double
Dim B As Variant
Dim c As Integer
Dim x As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Variant
Dim r As Variant
Dim Mx As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim target As Double
Set wks = Worksheets("comefri")
Set wkks = Worksheets("TEST")
Dim p As Long

'RPM INPUT
A = wkks.Range("C18").value
'Static Pressure Input
B = wkks.Range("C19").value
'copy comefri values to test sheet
Sheets("comefri").Range("A9:gs24").Copy Destination:=Sheets("test").Range("a1:gs16")
    
With test
    ' Row Numb used in rangelookup
    c = Range("C20").value
    d = Range(Cells(c, 102), Cells(c, 201))
    
    For Each cell In [a2:gs16]
        cell = WorksheetFunction.Round(cell, 1)
    Next cell
       
    'Finds RPM cell location
    Set cell = Range("a:a").find(What:=A, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=fasle, SearchFormat:=False)
    Range("c20") = cell.row
    'finds static.press cell location 
    target = B
    Set rng = Range(Cells(c, 102), Cells(c, 201))
    'rng.Offset(, 1).ClearContents
    Mx = Application.Max(rng)
    For Each B In rng
        If Abs(target - B) < Mx Then
            Mx = Abs(target - B)
            i = B.row
            p = B.Column
        End If
    Next B
   
    Debug.Print i
    Debug.Print p
    Range("d19").value = p
    Range("e19").value = i
    
End With

End Sub
```

The first time the code runs, I think it uses the values from previous inputs and the second time I run it, it uses the new inputs.
I think I need a line of code to clear old inputs.

Comment: Not related to your question, but a comment on your formatting:  You can "sprinkle" your dimensions throughout your code, rather than having a giant wall of dimensions.  If you move `i` or `p` in front of their first usage, you don't have to scroll up/down to check necessary debugging information.

Comment: Have you re-purposed `B`?  At first it's a value (maybe Double or Long), then you begin using it as a range within your loop.  I recognize you listed `as Variant`, though that seems like bad practice.

Comment: Additional comment, use variables that have meaning... in a month if you come back to this code, what is `A` without having to find the associated comment?  Just label it `RPMinput`, then you don't need a comment and the code is something you can follow in the future?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pull the value of `c` from a cell value (`Sheets("TEST").Range("C20")`).  You update the cell value (on this line: `Range("c20") = cell.row`), but don't update the value of `c`.  As such, when you set your `rng` variable, it's still using the old `c` value.

To resolve this, instead of this:

```
Set rng = Range(Cells(c, 102), Cells(c, 201))
```

Use this:

```
Set rng = wkks.Range(wkks.Cells(cell.Row, 102), wkks.Cells(cell.Row,201))
```

Lastly some generic advice:

- As Cyril already stated, use descriptive variable names instead of single letters
- Once a variable is set in the code, use the variable instead of referencing worksheet cells
- Use proper indenting for your code to make it easier to read and follow
- Always fully qualify your range objects to avoid confusion
- Use your worksheet objects that you set instead of referencing worksheets by their codename